# Switching display style property between "none" and "flex" with Animated from React-Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, animation

How can I switch between display none and flex using animated values?
I tried interpolating to 0 and 1 and depending on the value change the display property.

I am trying to hide the Animated.View when the animated value reaches 90 but nothing is happening.

```
// change animated value from 0 to 180
const flip = () => {
    Animated.timing(flipAnimation, {
      toValue: 180,
      duration: 300,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

//if the animated value is between 0 and 90 it will return 0 else it will return 1
const interpolate = flipAnimation.interpolate({
                          inputRange: [0, 90, 91, 180],
                          outputRange: [0, 0, 1, 1],
                      })
      
//if the value is 1 set display to "none" else set it to "flex"
<Animated.view style={{
    display: interpolate === 1 ? "none" : "flex"
}}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what ended up working for my needs, I gave up trying to make it work with Animated and just used reanimated:

```
const hideFrontStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      display: flipAnimation.value >= 90 ? "flex" : "none",
    };
  });
```